# PayPal MPL is not compatible with ios7

Tags: paypal, ios7

we have a serious problem with paypal mobile payment library running on our app built with the ios7 sdk.

we can initialise the library with success, but any attempt to open the paypal interface to ask a pre-approval causes the application to freeze and crash.

this is always replicable and affects any version of our app built with ios7.

this is not an attempt to talk about ios7 sdk, but just to understand if there is a resolution for this or if we should expect an update from paypal.

Comment: Don't you think actually asking someone at paypal would get you a better answer?

Comment: I would like to understand if this affects only my app or if there are other users which had the same experience (also in the past) and how they solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, we see it too.
It seems to crash at: PayPalViewClass initShowMerchantName: + 50 at PayPalViewClass.m:57

See also: https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/issues/14

Comment: so this seems definitely related to the internal library implementation.
is this happening as an attempt to show the pre-approval interface or it happens also in other cases?

Comment: It happens on checkout: 
\[\[PayPal getPayPalInst\] checkoutWithPayment:currentPayment\]
At that moment the paypal view should appear, but it doesn't get that far.